# How does Spring Data Neo4j begin transaction work?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a comprehension question. I cannot understand how the database actions from the Neo4jTemplate like "getOrCreateNode()" belong to the surrounding transction. How is it implemented? The Neo4jTemplate would be shared in a multi-threaded environment? I cannot see a distinct membership of the transaction. I would understand if the actions are directly in the transaction object (e.g. tx.getOrCreateNode()).

```
@Service
public class TestService {

 @Autowired
 private Neo4jTemplate template;

  public void save(IndexedTriple triple) {
    GraphDatabase gdb = template.getGraphDatabase();
    Transaction tx = gdb.beginTx();

    Node subject = gdb.getOrCreateNode()
    ...

    tx.success();
    tx.finish();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The below extract from the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e2468) pretty much sums it up. Use the spring transaction manager instead of using the Neo4j transactions and let spring take care of demarcation. Also, the transaction management is completely thread-safe. For you, I suggest using `@Transactional` annotation. If there is an existing transaction already, then spring joins that existing transaction as well.

> Transactions
>
> The Neo4jTemplate provides implicit transactions for some of its
>   methods. For instance save uses them. For other modifying operations
>   please provide Spring Transaction management using `@Transactional` or
>   the `TransactionTemplate`.